# MongoDB compare two fields & sum another field on all docs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Sample Docs :**

```
db.l5p1s3.insertMany([{x1:0,x2:0,v:0.08},{x1 : 0,x2:1,v:0.07},{x1:0,x2:2,v:0.04},{x1:0,x2:3,v:0.00}])
db.l5p1s3.insertMany([{x1:1,x2:0,v:0.06},{x1 : 1,x2:1,v:0.15},{x1:1,x2:2,v:0.05},{x1:1,x2:3,v:0.04}])
db.l5p1s3.insertMany([{x1:2,x2:0,v:0.05},{x1 : 2,x2:1,v:0.04},{x1:2,x2:2,v:0.10},{x1:2,x2:3,v:0.06}])
db.l5p1s3.insertMany([{x1:3,x2:0,v:0.00},{x1 : 3,x2:1,v:0.03},{x1:3,x2:2,v:0.04},{x1:3,x2:3,v:0.07}])
db.l5p1s3.insertMany([{x1:4,x2:0,v:0.00},{x1 : 4,x2:1,v:0.01},{x1:4,x2:2,v:0.05},{x1:4,x2:3,v:0.06}])
```

**Query :**

```
db.l5p1s3.aggregate({$match : { x1 :{$eq : "x2"} }} , {$group : {_id : {} , sum : {$sum : "$v"}}})
```

I have to get the sum of all values of **v** at `x1 == x2`. I tried the above query and did not get any output.

Comment: Let's say if you've these two docs :: `{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "v": 0.08,
    "x1": 0,
    "x2": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "v": 0.15,
    "x1": 1,
    "x2": 1
  }` Do you want to get combine there two docs & get final value as `sum : 0.23` ? Or do you want to keep these two as two different docs cause 1st doc's `x1,x2` != 2nd doc's `x1,x2` ? Just in case if you want to keep those two as separate check this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/MlKATveyiFV)

Comment: Just Replace group stage with this :: `{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        x1: "$x1",
        x2: "$x2"
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: "$v"
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `match` stage (`{$match : { x1 :{$eq : "x2"} }}`) says get all docs where `x1` field has string value `x2` - which is not what you're looking for. So to compare two fields & get required o/p, try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Matches docs where x1 == x2 */
  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$x1", "$x2"] } } },
  /** Iterate over all docs & sum -up 'v' field */
  { $group: { _id: "", sum: { $sum: "$v" } } }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9hO_4uWyDiH)